# USB tethering: Raspi loses it's ip if the host is restarted

Tags: networking, usb, pi-4, raspbian-buster

currently I'm playing with USB tethering between a raspi and a Linux PC.
On the Linux pc I configured the USB interface to get a static ip once it's connected. This is managed by the Networkmanager and works fine.
On the raspi I configured a static ip via `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
allow-hotplug usb0
iface usb0 inet static
  address 169.254.100.2
  netmask 255.255.255.252
  gateway 169.254.100.1
```

So now when I connect the raspi via USB to the Linux PC, the interface is detected and I can ssh into the raspi.
But if I reboot my Linux PC, I cannot reach the raspi any more. And now I found out that the raspi loses it's ip but does not reassign it if the Linux PC is back up.
I always have to execute `ip a add 169.254.100.2/30 dev usb0` on the raspi to get the network back.
Can you please give me any hint on what to do to get the network automatically back? At the moment I'm out of ideas.

Many thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: 169. IS NOT a static IP. It is a Link-local address.

Comment: @Milliways: If you assign it this way, it *IS* a static IP address, but it is in the range assigned to APIPA  (169.254.0.0/16). You should not do that of course.

Comment: @LjmDullaart true, but it remains unroutable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all your helpful suggestions!
The solution for my problem was to uninstall dhcpcd5
`apt purge dhcpcd5` and only using `/etc/network/interfaces`
After doing this I get my static ip (even if it's a local link address) back every time.
Even when using `etc/dhcpcd.conf` only (like @ingo suggested), my raspi always lost it's address if I use 196.254.100.2.
It only worked if I used a non local link address, for example 192.254.100.2.
But using the link local address to me is essential, since it should not interfere with any network connected to the host, whatever ip address it may have.

To be more precisely, here's what the dhcpcd logged when I used a static ip of the link local range

```
Feb 14 10:12:01 pi-display dhcpcd[252]: usb0: waiting for carrier
Feb 14 10:12:01 pi-display dhcpcd[252]: usb0: carrier acquired
Feb 14 10:12:01 pi-display dhcpcd[252]: DUID 00:01:00:01:23:f7:fb:72:00:22:82:ff:ff:22
Feb 14 10:12:01 pi-display dhcpcd[252]: usb0: IAID 82:ff:ff:22
Feb 14 10:12:01 pi-display dhcpcd[252]: usb0: adding address fe80::e2fc:7c06:450:7284
Feb 14 10:12:01 pi-display dhcpcd[252]: usb0: probing address 169.254.100.2/30
Feb 14 10:12:02 pi-display dhcpcd[252]: usb0: soliciting an IPv6 router
Feb 14 10:12:06 pi-display dhcpcd[252]: usb0: using static address 169.254.100.2/30
Feb 14 10:12:06 pi-display dhcpcd[252]: usb0: adding route to 169.254.100.0/30
Feb 14 10:12:06 pi-display dhcpcd[252]: usb0: adding default route via 169.254.100.1
Feb 14 10:12:06 pi-display dhcpcd[252]: usb0: deleting route to 169.254.100.0/30
Feb 14 10:12:06 pi-display dhcpcd[252]: usb0: deleting default route via 169.254.100.1
Feb 14 10:12:15 pi-display dhcpcd[252]: usb0: no IPv6 Routers available
```

And here's the log when I use a normal ip like 192.254.100.2:

```
Feb 14 10:12:01 pi-display dhcpcd[262]: usb0: waiting for carrier
Feb 14 10:12:01 pi-display dhcpcd[262]: usb0: carrier acquired
Feb 14 10:12:01 pi-display dhcpcd[262]: DUID 00:01:00:01:23:f7:fb:72:00:22:82:ff:ff:22
Feb 14 10:12:01 pi-display dhcpcd[262]: usb0: IAID 82:ff:ff:22
Feb 14 10:12:01 pi-display dhcpcd[262]: usb0: adding address fe80::e2fc:7c06:450:7284
Feb 14 10:12:01 pi-display dhcpcd[262]: usb0: probing address 192.254.100.2/30
Feb 14 10:12:01 pi-display dhcpcd[262]: usb0: soliciting an IPv6 router
Feb 14 10:12:07 pi-display dhcpcd[262]: usb0: using static address 192.254.100.2/30
Feb 14 10:12:07 pi-display dhcpcd[262]: usb0: adding route to 192.254.100.0/30
Feb 14 10:12:07 pi-display dhcpcd[262]: usb0: adding default route via 192.254.100.1
Feb 14 10:12:15 pi-display dhcpcd[262]: usb0: no IPv6 Routers available
```

Answer (score 3):

You ignored the note in `/etc/network/interfaces`:

> Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
> For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'

Please reset it to its default setting without any stanza:

```
rpi ~$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'

# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d
```

and use only `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` for your configuration if you don't know the impact of using `/etc/network/interaces` together with **dhcpcd**. You cannot simply mix it.

Comment: Will that take care of his use of the link local address also?

Comment: @Seamus link local addressing is enabled by default and should still work.

Comment: Yeah - I was referring to his comment: `I always have to execute ip a add 169.254.100.2/30 dev usb0 on the raspi to get the network back.`

Comment: @Seamus Such a command is not needed if he don't mix up things.

Comment: After playing around with the static ip address in `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` it turned out that if I use e.g. 192.254.100.2/30 the whole thing just works all the time. But why can't I use the local link address range 169.254.100.0?

Comment: @Chris Subnet 169.254.0.0/16 is reserved for [link local addressing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address). It is not a good idea to use addresses from that subnet as static because the static ip address is not arp probed if it already given to another device.